# How to set a rounded value from double number

Tags: java, android, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to calculate the average based on user input. Now I've got the basics working. But when i put in numbers that would be 1\3's etc. I get the whole serie of numbers, when that happens I want it rounded of to 1 number. Just like it does with 'normal' numbers like 5.0

Any explanation or tips etc. are welcome!

```
final TextView averageView = findViewById(R.id.averageView); 
final String averageText = getString(R.string.average); 
final Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateAverageButton); 

calaculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() { 
    @SupressLint("SetTextI18n")                                                     
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        double grade[]  = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1)).getText().toString()); 
        double weight[] = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight1)).getText().toString()); 
        double weightTotal = weight[0]; double sum = grade[0] * weight[0] 
        double average = sum / weightTotal 
        averageView.setText(averageText + " " + Double.toString(average));
```

Comment: If you want to round off the value then you can Use the function `Math.round(value)` for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.format()` to round the number.

```
String result = String.format("%.2f", your_double_variable);
```

You can also use DecimalFormat class.

```
double avg;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
ans = Double.valueOf(df.format(avg));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use round method of Math utility class

```
Math.round(average,1);
```